# Could not autowire. No beans of 'AuthenticationEntryPoint' type found

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, autowired

I get an warning like this when I Autowired any class except the classes I created.

IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1

Spring boot version: 2.7.4

**Warning:**

```
Could not autowire. No beans of 'AuthenticationEntryPoint' type found.
```

**Security class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
   
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        .....
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**Configuration class for My Created Class ComponentScan**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.security"})
public class SecurityConfiguration {}
```

**spring.factories**

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
com.example.SecurityConfiguration
```

There is no this problem in my own classes.
but there is this problem in other classes.
How can i solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SpringWeb was implemented AuthenticationEntryPoint class in package
`org.Springframework.Security.Web.Authentication`
, but they have not been registered for a component, So you can't use @Autowired to auto-inject. You can try writing its Bean generation function, for example

```
@Bean
public LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint instance(){
    return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login");
}
```

Or try add your own `AuthenticationEntryPoint` class to your project

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        //your commence here....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use constructor injection as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfig{


private AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint) {
    this.authEntryPoint = authEntryPoint;
}
}
```

or of you use lombok:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
 public class SecurityConfig{


private final AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;


}
```

Comment: I've tried before. gives the same warning.